# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled in MAC YOSEMITE

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am trying to install mongo on mac os X yosemite, i have already installed the current version of PECL mongo db ad mongo extension files mongo.so, but still this error The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled comes when i open any kind of localhost page, please help i have been stuck in this situation since a week, also i have tried other versions of mongo too but the error appears to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i finally found the solution. 
I used homebrew to install pecl extension.

then actually i was using

```
    sudo vi php.ini
```

command to edit and insert the mongo.so extension

but later i downloaded sublime text edited the note and inserted the extension manually and restarted xampp